# flink tumbling window is not triggered (no watermark strategy)

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

**Problem statement:** stream events from kafka source. These event payloads are of string format. Parse them into Documents and batch insert them into DB every 5 seconds based on event time.

`map()` functions are getting executed. But program control is not going into `apply()`. Hence bulk insert is not happening. I tried with keyed and non-keyed windows. None of them are working. No error is being thrown.

flink version: 1.15.0

Below is the code for my main method. How should I fix this?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    streamExecutionEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);


    KafkaConfig kafkaConfig = Utils.getAppConfig().getKafkaConfig();

    logger.info("main() Loading kafka config :: {}", kafkaConfig);

    KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(kafkaConfig.getBootstrapServers())
        .setTopics(kafkaConfig.getTopics())
        .setGroupId(kafkaConfig.getConsumerGroupId())
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema()).build();

    logger.info("main() Configured kafka source :: {}", kafkaSource);

    DataStreamSource<String> dataStream = streamExecutionEnv.fromSource(kafkaSource,
        WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "mySource");

    logger.info("main() Configured kafka dataStream :: {}", dataStream);

    DataStream<Document> dataStream1 = dataStream.map(new DocumentMapperFunction());

    DataStream<InsertOneModel<Document>> dataStream2 = dataStream1.map(new InsertOneModelMapperFunction());

    DataStream<Object> dataStream3 = dataStream2
        .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(0)))
            /*.keyBy(insertOneModel -> insertOneModel.getDocument().get("ackSubSystem"))
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))*/
        .apply(new BulkInsertToDB2())
            .setParallelism(1);

    logger.info("main() before streamExecutionEnv execution");

    dataStream3.print();

    streamExecutionEnv.execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Event time windows require a watermark strategy. Without one, the windows are never triggered.

Furthermore, even with `forMonotonousTimestamps`, a given window will not be triggered until Flink has processed at least one event belonging to the following window from every Kafka partition. (If there are idle (or empty) Kafka partitions, you should use `withIdleness` to withdraw those partitions from the overall watermark calculations.)

Comment: I have used `WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps()` and used 
`TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))`. But still apply() is not getting triggered after 30 seconds

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include the most likely causes.

Answer (score 2):

Use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows instead Event time windows.

As David has mentioned TumblingEventTimeWindows requires watermark strategy.